# UITableViewCell Show editactions programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am hoping there is a way to programmatically display the swipe left edittask list for a given cell. I tried everything I could think of to get it to display but nothing seems to work.

[image]

I am able to show them with a swipe left without issue but I need the ability to show them programmatically.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: "I tried everything I could think of" What exactly did you try? You understand that this is a scroll view, yes?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Did the answer below help?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `editing` on the cell. According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/editing) from Apple, it should display the edit actions.